# how can i decrease the product price on cart page?

Tags: magento

If the user has an existing account balance, I'd like to give him the option to specify how much of his previous balance to apply to the item and sync this info with the cart and order. I have already implemented the user's account balance, both on the front and back end.

Would a coupon-like system work best, or should I try something else?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: How did you add the balance to the customer account in the first place? Is it an extension or a manually set attribute?

Comment: If you're using Store Credit in enterprise edition then it already allows customers to draw on their credit as a payment option. If you're making your own implementation then it would make sense to follow the same pattern; Make it a payment method that is seen on the checkout page.

Answer (score 0):

I would let the customer decrease its cart total with the balance would be more simple / logic for the customer also (?)
What E-commerce solution do you use? Magento(?) If so there are coupon extensions that can handle this.

You could also build a simple balance system where users would see there balance in there account ( if such feature is implemented) or just mail them a message with a unique code that you save in DB + the value of balance then use this code as a coupon on checkout.

Comment: Maybe we can do this.But i have make a extension in which i have created a observer file. the purpose of this file is check that user has previous balance or not?

Answer (score 0):

We have created quite a few e-commerce solutions up to date. Usually, when user balance is involved, then what you do is create two transactions referred to one invoice. In the first transaction specify the amount taken from balance, where as leave the other transaction for whatever checkout method you use. Upon callback from the checkout, see if the balance paid matches the invoice to mark it as paid respectfully.

Alternatively, you can use discount - decrease user balance and add "discount" to the order. It all depends on your accounting needs and preferences.

Comment: I have already try this. But whenever user reach on next step then its index controller again reset the amount.

Comment: @Rohit: In what programming language, framework or (open source) e-commerce solution do you work? Ah missed that... Magento it is indeed. I would suggest trying one of the coupon extensions from the magento extension website, magenta is a big beast and a pain to code for yourself, at least not with extensive learning!

Comment: thanks for your kind advise but i have already created a extension in which i have make observer file which decrease the amount successfully.\

Answer (score 0):

On Amazon they allow you to apply any unused balance to the existing order. Its when you checkout that they say you have $150 credit on your account, would you like to apply this to your order, it defaults to yes in a tick box.

Its quite neat and simple, it doesn't allow you to apply a part amount from what I've seen.

Then when you go to payment you pay $total - balance.

So if you have $200 total, the payment via credit card would be for the $50.